# Why do I need to "reopenClass" to set the url for an ember-data model?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I found that if I try to include the url in the original definition of an ember-data model it blows up in my REST adapter but if I simply "reopenClass" it's fine.

What is the technical reason behind this? (below is the working example)

```
CodeCamp.Speaker = DS.Model.extend({
    id: DS.attr('number'),
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    session: DS.belongsTo('CodeCamp.Session')
});

CodeCamp.Speaker.reopenClass({
    url: 'sessions/%@/speakers'
});
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Calling `extend` on an object sets instance attributes, whereas `reopenClass` sets class attributes.

The `url` attribute is a class-level attribute,

```
Ember.get(CodeCamp.Speaker, 'url')
```

as opposed to:

```
speaker = CodeCamp.Speaker.createObject()
Ember.get(speaker, 'name')
```

Comment: awesome! exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: but isnt `DS.Model` a class and NOT an object? Why do you then say we are calling extend on an object? I am a bit confused.

Answer (score 0):

Note also that you can extend an instance by using simply `reopen`. Emberjs' docu contains an example which you find at http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/reopening-classes-and-instances/