# EmberJS: How to provide a specific URL for a model in ember-data RESTAdapter?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, url-routing

Question 1:
If I have a ember-data model called "Company", how do I tell it to hit `/businesses` and `/businesses/:id` to retrieve records instead? Is there a way to specify the url for a given model? Even better, like BackboneJS, can I compute a URL for the model at runtime?

Questions 2:
I have somewhat a unique requirement, my API is organized this way:

`/api/v1/company/:company_id/form/:form_id/items/:item_id`

Is there a way to handle this with EmberJS? I understand ember has the DS.hasMany('App.Items') kind of relationships, but they seem to hit the `/items/:item_id` URL to get the data instead of the full URL.

How do I deal with this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering to your first question, when you're creating your store, you can do this:

```
DS.RESTAdapter.configure("plurals", {
  company: "businesses"
});
```

As for your second question, based on [these guides](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_url-conventions) I believe you can a namespace like the following, replacing the ids with your company and form information, but I haven't done this before so I can't tell for sure this would work. Assuming you land in your application knowing these ids, you could technically replace them:

```
DS.RESTAdapter.reopen({
  namespace: '/api/v1/company/<replace>/form/<replace>'
})
```

You could also try setting the model `url`.

You can read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12679998/why-do-i-need-to-reopenclass-to-set-the-url-for-an-ember-data-model)

Comment: Thanks, I believe the `url` property is what I'm after. Could you tell me where in the code this exist? I've been tearing through the ember-data github codebase and can't seem to find it (bit confusing sometimes since classes are reopened in all kinds of places)... (will mark ur answer soon - just testing the solution)

Comment: Frankly don't see how the `url` property works. I'm looking at the `buildURL` method in the `RESTAdapter`... it simply adds the following: `adapter.url + namespace + pluralize(record) + suffix`. pluralize simply maps the plurals. There's no use of the model's url property at all. I've tried and can't get it to work either.

Comment: Perhaps it's no longer in use; like I said, I'm not really sure about that part of your question. Maybe you want to check http://discuss.emberjs.com and see if anyone can help there too

Comment: Thanks, I've given you a tick since you answered all the rest of it! Much appreciated.

Comment: Reposted: 
http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/calculating-a-url-for-a-given-model-for-restadapter/365