# Find in store with slug (ember)

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

According to ember data documentation, if i want to make a call on my back-end application such as /applications/123 i use the code below.

adapters/application.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'api/v1',
  host:'http://xxxxx.com/',   
});
```

routes/home.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function (params) {
        return this.store.find("Application", params.id);
    }
});
```

But, i want to make a call like /applications/123/analytics, where analytic's call is

```
model: function () {
   return this.store.find('Analytic');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override the adapter for `photos` make build a different url by overriding `urlForFind`:

```
App.PhotoAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  urlForFind: function(){ 
    return this._super() + "/types";
  }
});
```

Comment: @thodwris This way is really decent, I wouldn't know how it could be improved upon.

Comment: Please see my updated question! Thanx anyway for your help!

Comment: @thodwris It's a different question now. What you're doing is non-standard, but you can probably just override the AnalyticAdapters namespace on figuring out what your application id is, like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15364971/29347